# Is it possible to use the mousedown and mouseup event on the same button?

Tags: jquery, html, arduino

This project involves controlling a toy car over LAN.

On my html page, there are 5 "buttons";up, down, left, right, stop.
My code works like this: Say the user clicks on "up", a value gets sent to a php page for processing and the processed string gets printed on another php page for an arduino to read.

For the car to stop, the user has to click on stop.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<form name="motorform" action="motorboardprocess.php" method="post">
<tr><p align='center'><font face="BN machine" size="6" color="royalblue">Motor Shield</font></tr>
<tr>
    <input id="forward" type="image" src="up.png" name="forward">
</tr> 
<tr>
    <input id="left" type="image" src="left.png"  name="left">
    <input id="stop"type="image" src="stop.png"  name="stop">
    <input id="right" type="image" src="right.png" name="right">
</tr>
<tr>      
    <input id="backward" type="image" src="down.png" name="backward">
</tr>   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the said php...

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['forward_x'], $_POST['forward_y'])){
    $myFile = "mtboardcom.php";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");    
    $stringData = "<?php\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "echo ".'"<forward>"'."\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "?>\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);        
}

else if (isset($_POST['left_x'], $_POST['left_y'])){
    $myFile = "mtboardcom.php";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");    
    $stringData = "<?php\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "echo ".'"<left>"'."\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "?>\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);        
}
//and so on.....
```

the arduino reads:

```
<?php
    echo "<forward>"
?>
```

So the question is, how do I make use of the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events from jquery
to remove the stop 'button'.

Or another scenario: the user holds down the button to move the car and releases the button to stop the car.

On `mousedown`, a string `'forward'` is read by the arduino.

`mouseup` on the same button, string `'stop'` is read by the arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can subscribe to two different events in Javascript. just hook into the events:

```
var field = document.getElementsById('#idName');

field.onmousedown = function(){

}

field.onmouseup = function(){

}
```

Or for jquery:

```
var field = $('#idName');

field.mousedown(function(){

}).mouseup(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, this is very simple:

```
$('#element').mousedown(function (event) {
    // process mouse down
});
$('#element').mouseup(function (event) {
    // process mouse up
});
```

You can also chain them with

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    /* code */
}).mouseup(function (event) {
    /* code */
});
```

During these events, you can ping your URL with a `$.ajax` call. But do note that because AJAX is asynchronous, you could be looking at race conditions if you're not careful. Because they are coming from 1 client, you should be fine, but there could be other issues that could cause slight delays or differences in response times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jquery code. Added a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/j6cBX/2/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='btn' style='width:50px;height:30px;background-color:red'>Click</div>
    <div id='log'></div>

<script>
    $("#btn").mouseup(function(){
      $('#log').append('<span style="color:#F00;">Mouse up.</span>');
    }).mousedown(function(){
      $('#log').append('<span style="color:#00F;">Mouse down.</span>');
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `#log` div isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can catch both mousedown and mouseup events, but you need to use AJAX calls to send the information to the server so that you don't do a postback that reloads the page.

Also, you don't automatically get a mouseup event that corresponds to each mousedown event. The user might move the mouse outside the button before releasing the button, and even move it to a different button. You should store which button was pressed in a Javascript variable, and catch the mouseup event for the entire page instead of for the buttons, and send a stop signal if the last click was on a button.