# mousedown event using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, raspberry-pi, gpio

The code I have working on is that once I click on a button, two motors would spin continuously until I hit a different button to stop. I want to be able to press and hold a button to spin the motors, but once let go of that button, the motor stops.

**Portion of my remoteControl.php file:**

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
$pin = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pin']);
        if ($action == "forward"){
        $setting = "1";
        mysql_query("UPDATE pinStatus SET pinStatus='$setting' WHERE pinNumber='17';");
        mysql_query("UPDATE pinStatus SET pinStatus='$setting' WHERE pinNumber='22';");
        mysql_close();
        header('Location: remoteControl.php'); ..........
........
<form action="remoteControl.php" method="get">
<input id="forward" type="image" src="uparrow.jpg" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:150px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:50px; HEIGHT:50px;">
<input type=hidden name="action" value="forward">
</form>
```

**JavaScript I'm trying to get working:**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnButtonDown (button) {
            "can't figure out what to put";
        }
        function OnButtonUp (button) {
            "can't figure out what to put";
        }

        function Init () {
            var button = document.getElementById ("forward");
            if (button.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
                button.addEventListener ("mousedown", function () {OnButtonDown (button)}, false);
                button.addEventListener ("mouseup", function () {OnButtonUp (button)}, false);
            }
            else {
                if (button.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
                    button.attachEvent ("onmousedown", function () {OnButtonDown (button)});
                    button.attachEvent ("onmouseup", function () {OnButtonUp (button)});
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Init ()">
```

Comment: What "motors" are you talking about?

Comment: So, your looking for code that will make a image spin?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'm working on the Raspberry Pi. I'm using it as a web server and the Raspberry also has GPIO (output pins), which I'm using to drive or spin DC motors. Once I click on the uparrow image, it send commands to spin the DC motor.

Comment: When pin 17 and pin 22 goes high on the Raspberry Pi, it spins the motors.

Comment: You're going to be more clear on what exactly you want. And how exactly you control said motors.

Comment: Is your question just how to get the `OnButtonDown()` and `OnButtonUp()` functions to invoke the PHP server script? Read up on AJAX.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084687/is-it-possible-to-use-the-mousedown-and-mouseup-event-on-the-same-button

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get javascript to indirectly invoke PHP. I've read up on AJAX, jquery...but wasn't able to figure out.

Comment: I'll try to read up more on AJAX then and see what I can find.

Comment: Still trying to get it to work, but I want to give credit to 'drcurzon' for a great start/tutorial on the Rasperry Pi: http://www.instructables.com/id/Web-Control-of-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO/#step1

Answer (score 1):

When the mouse is down you call OnButtonDown and when it is up you call OnButtonUp. If that is working, the only issue is that you don't know what to do on that functions in order to update your DB with the status (I suppose that there is some kind of controller that check the status on the DB and update GPIO state).

You need to call the file remoteControl.php (that takes a GET parameter to update the DB).
This can be done using ajax function from jquery.

```
<head>
<!-- First we include jquery library. In this case from Google CDN -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnButtonDown (button) {
        //We pass the parameter forward to remoteControl.php
         $.ajax({
            data:  action=forward,
            url:   'remoteControl.php',
            type:  'get',
            success:  function (response) {

            }
         });
    }
    function OnButtonUp (button) {
        //Here the same as in OnButtonDown but passing another parameter
    }

    function Init () {
        var button = document.getElementById ("forward");
        if (button.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
            button.addEventListener ("mousedown", function () {OnButtonDown (button)}, false);
            button.addEventListener ("mouseup", function () {OnButtonUp (button)}, false);
        }
        else {
            if (button.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
                button.attachEvent ("onmousedown", function () {OnButtonDown (button)});
                button.attachEvent ("onmouseup", function () {OnButtonUp (button)});
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are the man!!!!!! Got the button working!!!!! I did had to use " " instead of ' ' for the data, url, and type. Just have to do a little polishing by changing from button to image now since I'm using an image file.

Comment: Scratch that...no need to change from button to image. All set. Thanks a lot Anjz. You are a life saver. How do I close this question as being solved?

Comment: There is a "check" button on the left side of the answer if you click there you accept the answer as the correct one.